# Centering a simple binary (black or white pixels) in python

Tags: image, python-2.7

I have a simple black and white image (all pixels are either 255 or 0) that I would like to center (the image is actually a 2D mask that I used to extract information from another image).  I would like to find the max/min row/column locations of he black pixels so that I can center it relative to the max/min boundaries of the image.  A typical mask looks like this:
[image]

In the end, I would like to calculate the distance from the points circled in red to the image boundaries and use that to shift the image.  I'm guessing there is a clever way to do this in Python but I haven't figured it out yet.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this.  The black values are 255, white values are 0.  If you average values in the direction of both axes and apply np.nonzero to the result, you can get the indices of the max and min.  So, if the name of the image was trench_filter, the following would find the min's and max's:

```
x_max = np.max(np.mean(trench_filter,axis=0).nonzero())
x_min = np.min(np.mean(trench_filter,axis=0).nonzero())
y_max = np.max(np.mean(trench_filter,axis=1).nonzero())
y_min = np.min(np.mean(trench_filter,axis=1).nonzero())
```